# how to tell assertJsonEquals to ignore one field in comparing

Tags: java, json, junit, assert, jsonunit

I am using **assertJsonEquals** of [JsonUnit](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit)

I do the following in my code:

```
assertJsonEquals(resource("ExpecedResponse.json"),
                         ActualResponse, when(IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER));
```

The `ActualResponse` has the response from a HTTP POST.

The `ExpectedResponse.json` is a json file with some fields as follows for e.g:

```
{
  "columnNames": [
    "date",
    "signalType",
    "userId",
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      222555888,
      "OUT",
      "000-000-111-444"
    ],
    [
      333666999,
      "IN",
      "000-000-222-333"
    ],
  ],
  "lastUpdatedTimestamp": "2018-01-26T00:00:00Z"
}
```

I compare the two responses with assertJsonEquals.

**My question is: How do I tell it to ignore checking the `lastUpdatedTimestamp` field but check everything else with assertJsonEquals or any other library that you can recommend?!**

If I remove the lastUpdatedTimestamp from ExpectedResponse.json, then it complains that it is missing!

Would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you remove the timestamps from the Jsons and then assert? That might require mapping them into some kind of JSONObject

Comment: It complains if removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the library https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert that has an assert method that allows customization.

Here's an example of a test that is passing (and such ignoring the value of the `time` field)

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws JSONException {
    JSONAssert.assertEquals("{x: 1, time:123}",
                            "{x: 1, time:234}",
                            new CustomComparator(
                              JSONCompareMode.STRICT,
                              Customization.customization("time", // json path you want to customize
                                                          new ValueMatcher() {
                                @Override public boolean equal(Object o1, Object o2) {
                                  return true; // in your case just ignore the values and return true
                                }
                              }))
    );
  }
```

Here's the link to the javadoc of the assertEquals method that I am using in the example: http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/apidocs/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/JSONAssert.html#assertEquals-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.comparator.JSONComparator-

Comment: is there anyway to ignore multiple fields say `startDate` and `endDate`?

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit#ignoring-paths) says:

```
assertJsonEquals(
   "{\"root\":{\"test\":1, \"ignored\": 2}}", 
   "{\"root\":{\"test\":1, \"ignored\": 1}}", 
   whenIgnoringPaths("root.ignored")
);
```

Comment: can I provide multiple options? I want to use `whenIgnoringPaths("root.ignored")` and `JsonAssert.when(Option.IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER)`

Answer (score 0):

To ignore only one field add '@IGNORE" to the expected json and then set setIgnorePlaceholder as below

```
JsonAssert.setTolerance(0.0000001);
JsonAssert.setOptions(IGNORING_ARRAY_ORDER);
JsonAssert.setIgnorePlaceholder("@IGNORE"); //You have to tag the ignored values in ExpecedResponse.json with "@IGNORE"

assertJsonEquals(resource("ExpecedResponse.json"),
                         ActualResponse);
```

Comment: Please, add some context to your answer :)